# Getting the friendly name for a Process after starting it

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm coding a watchdog service for an embedded system that monitors some proprietary processes and restarts them if necessary. (Nothing to do with *malware*, before you ask. It's just a business requirement)

I need to **retrieve the friendly name from a process I have just created**, so that later I can retrieve that process using that name in order to monitor its health.

My problem is as follows:

- If I try to read `Process.ProcessName` right after `Process.Start()`, I get an `InvalidOperationException` because it the process has not been fully created yet.
- The same happens if I use `Process.WaitForInputIdle()`, but since this requires a message pump and many executables could be UI-less launchers for the actual application, this might not be an option.
- I **need** to get the friendly name right after creating the process, before doing anything else.

Here's a code snippet:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "notepad.exe" };
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForInputIdle();
var friendlyName = process.ProcessName;
```

This will throw an `InvalidOperationException` on the last line if the process being started is Firefox, for example.

So how would I do this? Is there a safer method?

EDIT: Added a code snippet for clarification.
EDIT2: Rephrased the whole question for clarification, left irrelevant stuff out.

Comment: Do the processes being monitored start a message pump? If not, `WaitForInputIdle` will not do anything at all. Perhaps you can work with `Process.MainModule` instead to find the name of the executable?

Comment: Thought of that, yeah. But in my test case, the process is Firefox.

Comment: Do you mean `Process.MainModule.ModuleName`? Does it always return the same value as `Process.ProcessName`?

Comment: How about showing the code that you are using.. so that there is no misunderstanding..

Comment: @AxelMagagnini: Can't answer that definitively. But isn't the name of the executable good enough?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: There you go. :)

Comment: @Jon: If it **always** matched ProcessName minus the .exe extension, yes. But I'm not sure that is the case. Is it?

Comment: How can that code possibly work unless I am missing something here.. where do you define the process name..? do you get this error `Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.` the Error should happen after this line `process.Start()`

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Whoops, my bad. I missed a few lines while trying to simplify it. It's  fixed now, sorry.

Comment: LOL no Problem Axel what is this value by the way..? `theConfiguredProcessName`

Comment: Can you post an example of the friendly name and executable path that are set in the app.config?  Creating a `process[]' and a `foreach` loop will get you the name(s) of the processes...

Comment: Erm why not just take friendly name out of the config, then they can't bog it up, and you don't have to mess about like this?

Comment: @AxelMagagnini: Did you give thought to the possibility that the actual process you spawn may not be what a human would recognize as "Firefox"? For example in the case of FF it *could* be a UI-less launcher.

Comment: How is `theConfiguredProcessName` defined?

Comment: Axel there are some flaws in your code.. where you are looking for if the `ProcessName.Equals(theConfiguredProcessName)` this will not equal and the process.Name does get captured .. I will paste the code on what should work for you.. I will post a separate example using the .Contains Method() as well

Comment: @Brian: Good point. I just edited the question to clarify that. But I'm pretty sure it's getting the correct values.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: That's exactly what I am currently doing. The problem is that it's easy that someone -for example- adds the .exe to the process name, therefore I'd like to validate it.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I understand what you mean, but I don't think that's it, check my last edit (Starting with "NOTE") to see. The problem is that just trying to access `process.ProcessName` throws an exception because it is not yet available, so there's no way a comparison is even made.

Comment: I don't think that possible unless the process or name is not in the TaskManager it would really help if you would put actual values of what those variables are for the .exe as well as the value in the config file.. it can be mocked up by anyone to test but what you are saying and or expecting is not making sense

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you just said. But maybe you misunderstood the purpose of the code. The idea is to validate and correct `theConfiguredProcessName` if it does not match the actual `ProcessName` after starting the process. This value will be set by an user and can probably be wrong.

Comment: @Jon: That's a very good point, I didn't check for that. But that makes me think that using `Process.WaitForInputIdle()` is not an option at all, as there must be lots of similar cases.

Comment: I am not sure how the process name could be wrong.. perhaps I am misunderstanding you or perhaps you can rethink your question in a way that does not cause confusion.. what is the purpose of what you are trying to do.. a user should probably not care what the name of a process is as long as the process / application running does what it needs to do.. once it's started you I do not think that you can change the name unless you have another condition to stop that process and then pass the correct name which I think you will have errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of research I had to resort to a somewhat hacky solution.

According to the [Process.GetProcessesByName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326945%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) documentation, "*The process name is a friendly name for the process, such as Outlook, that does not include the .exe extension or the path.*".

Considering this, I worked around the problem using this code:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "notepad.exe" };
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
var friendlyName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(startInfo.FileName);
```

As I said, it still feels kinda hacky, but at least it got the job done and allowed me to move on.

Thanks for all your comments anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some key things in your code and try something like this using `NotePad.exe` and you will see what I am talking about

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "notepad.exe" };
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.Start();
process.WaitForInputIdle();
// this line below will always be false because `process.ProcessName will be 
//notepad and process.StartInfo.FileName = notepade.exe 
if (process.ProcessName.Equals(process.StartInfo.FileName) == false)
{
   var theConfiguredProcessName = process.ProcessName;
}
```

Another option you could do either of the next 2 things below

```
Process[] processName = Process.GetProcessesByName("blah.exe");
```

or check all processes running and check for your running process

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process process in processlist)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", process.ProcessName, process.Id);
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't think that's it. Actually, the comparison isn't even executed because just accessing `process.ProcessName` throws an exception, as it is not yet available. Besides, the goal of the question is to validate that value. So I start the process and if it doesn't match with the actual ProcessName, I correct it.

Comment: show the code where you are reading from the config file.. also if it does get the value.. then you need to append the file extension perhaps I access process.ProcessName it works on this end.. I would suggest putting break points and when you get to the `startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo` line look at the value of FileName when looking at startInfo step thru the code

Comment: As I said, the value is irrelevant, because I'm trying to validate and correct it. I think you might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think that I understand what you are wanting Axel and what I am saying now that I understand you is that I don't think that you can do that without having to have another conditional check so if you change the name ..then you will need to dynamically pass the `{FileName = someVariableName}` and since you are not making the process names the same in the config vs the process.ProcessName how do you plan to check that as well as change it.. you will need to kill that current process then spawn a new process

Comment: No, you still misunderstand me. Basically my problem is this: I need to know the friendly name of the process I have **just created**, so that I can monitor it later **getting it by name**. The rest does not matter. I can't do it with that code because accessing Process.ProcessName at this stage throws an exception (the process is not fully created yet). **THAT** is my problem. Not the values of any other variable. Anyway I don't think the `WaitForInputIdle()` method will work, because some .exes could be just UI-less launchers for the actual program.

Comment: ok I understand you but I am still wondering if the process has just been created..then perhaps you can do a While loop and check to see if the process is fully launched or running then set a flag true, then breakout of that loop then do your process code like you already have.. would that work..? then you won't need this `WaitForInputIdle()`

Comment: That's what `WaitForInputIdle()` does exactly. But only if the executed process has a message pump, which may not be the case (UI-less launchers). I don't think it's a good idea to do it on my side.

Comment: Axel I added something else keep in mind if that process has not made it to the TaskManager i.e process running you will get that error..

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort, but I think you keep misunderstanding what I'm trying to do. I need to A) Start the process, B) Find out what its friendly name is somehow (**this is the problem**) and C) Retrieve the process **later** using the name I found in B).

Comment: how about you send me the code and I can see exactly what the problem is.. some where along the communication chain here we are misunderstanding one another..

Comment: The code is in the question, and I honestly wouldn't know how to clarify this further, sorry.

Comment: well I am trying to lend you a helping hand and the code works fine on my end so not sure where in the process you are doing this.what event are you trying to do this..perhaps that's the issue not sure but maybe you can show more of what you are doing without pasting the whole program here